# Why can't I see my cluster when I'm trying to setup a scheduled task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, amazon-ecs, aws-event-bridge

I have a cluster in ECS with about 20+ services all happily running in it.

I've just uploaded a new image which I want to set up as a daily task.  I can create it as a task and run it - the logs indicate it is running to completion.

I've gone into EventBridge and created a Rule, set the detail and cron, I select the target (AWS service), then select ECS task but when I drop the Cluster dropdown it is empty, I can't select a cluster - there are none.

Is this a security issue perhaps or am I missing something elsewhere - can't this be done?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is certainly possible. Since you are doing this through the AWS web console, have you tried setting it up via the ECS Scheduled Tasks UI, instead of through the EventBridge UI? The same EventBridge configuration is created either way, but it may work better through the ECS UI.

Comment: Do you have the location (URL) for that (ECS Scheduled Tasks UI) please?

Comment: No, and I haven't used the AWS UI to create things like that in years. I use Terraform for that now. You might have to switch to the old ECS UI if you don't see it in the new UI.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually managed to get this to work. The problem was that I was starting the EventBridge creation process in the wrong region - rookie mistake - so it couldn't see the cluster in the other region. D'Oh!